# How can I use the Bootstrap Badge class within MVC Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How can I use the Bootstrap Badge class to show a number next to the button? In this case I am using the @ActionLink. I've seen on the bootstrap page that I'm supposed to use a HTML span for the Badge.

Code:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="list-group">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "list-group-item" })
                    @Html.ActionLink("Auto's", "Lijst", "Auto", null, new { @class = "list-group-item" })
                    @Html.ActionLink("Medewerkers", "Lijst", "Medewerker", null, new { @class = "list-group-item" })
 <!--This one!-->   @Html.ActionLink("Dagprogramma", "Dagprogramma", "Medewerker", null, new { @class = "list-group-item"} )
                    @Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home", null, new { @class = "list-group-item" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Isn't the badge just a span tag? <span class="badge">5</span> You would just put it to the left of that actionlink. If this isn't what you mean please clarify.

Comment: Didnt work, thanks anyway. It just puts the badge above the ActionLink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot include custom html markup inside the link markup generated by `ActionLink` helper method. What you can do is, write an anchor tag and include the span inside that. Use the `Url.Action` method to generate the correct relative url to the action method which you will use as the link's `href` attribute value.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Medewerkers", "Lijst", "Medewerker", null, 
                                                   new { @class = "list-group-item" })

  <a href="@Url.Action("Dagprogramma","Medewerker")"
                class="list-group-item"> Dagprogramma <span class="badge">99</span>
  </a>
  @Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home", null, 
                                                       new { @class = "list-group-item" })
```

Comment: I just tried this and it does work, but not the way it is supposed to. It creates an extra text and doesnt put the badge on the ActionLink.
Screenshot:  http://prntscr.com/9sotj3

Comment: Are you sure your markup is correct. I copied and pasted from the answer and tried it and it worked fine for me, http://prntscr.com/9sovgj